# Adding type to nested destructured props. Typescript React Redux. TS2339

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, jsx, react-tsx

The destructured props (from redux state) for the `mapStateToProps()` function are nested, how would I apply the `HeaderStateMap` types to it? I receive the following error message upon compilation:

```
Property 'cart' does not exist on type 'HeaderStateMap'.  TS2339
```

Also, I've set `user:any` for the meantime, but if I change the type to object, TypeScript complains that `Property 'user' does not exist on type '{}'`.

Would appreciate any help :).

**Code**

```
type HeaderStateMap = {
    user:any,
    hidden:boolean
};

const mapStateToProps = ({ user: { user }, cart: { hidden } }:HeaderStateMap) => {
    return {
        user,
        hidden
    };
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can nest your types:

```
interface User {
  name: string;
};

type HeaderStateMap = {
  user: User;
  cart: {
    hidden: boolean;
  };
};
```

About the bug you have, i think you are destructuring too far, you assume that you have user inside user object: `user.user`, try:

```
const mapStateToProps = ({ user, cart: { hidden } }:HeaderStateMap) =>
```